# PythonAnywhere web app that displays image gallery and votes for them. Votes (Likes) are to be stored in SQL database

Tags: python, sql, flask, pythonanywhere

So, I was trying to build a web app that stores image URLs in the database and the user has to like or dislike the post (image) and that vote is to be recorded in the database.
    I'd like to retrieve the database to see most-liked images or most-disliked, etc., For time being, I hard coded image URLs in my HTML code. I'm unable to connect these URLs to the database.
    I also included two functions `AddClick()` and `MinusClick()` in the HTML code to count Likes and Dislikes, but once the page refreshes, everything's gone.

I have created HTML page and flask_app.py to include database and render the HTML template.

`flask_app.py` code:

```
class Like(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "likes"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    image = db.Column(db.String(4096))
    count = db.Column(db.Integer)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    count = request.args.get('Clicks')
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("main_page.html")
    count = Like(content=request.form["Clicks"])
    db.session.add(count)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

`main_template.html` code:

```
<script>var Clicks = 0 ;
function AddClick(){
    Clicks = Clicks + 1;
    document.getElementById('CountedClicks').innerHTML = Clicks + ' Likes';
}
function MinusClick(){
    Clicks = Clicks - 1;
    document.getElementById('CountedClicks').innerHTML = Clicks + ' Likes';
}
</script>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <a class="lightbox" href="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/0*9kZ68wExkrUDFn4U.jpg">
                    <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/0*9kZ68wExkrUDFn4U.jpg" alt="3">
                </a>
                <span id="CountedClicks">0 Likes</span><br>
                    <button onclick="AddClick()">
                    <a class="social-like" >
                        <span class="like"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i></span>
                        <span class="count" >0</span>
                    </a>
                    </button>
                    &nbsp;
                    <button onclick="MinusClick()">
                    <a class="social-dislike" >
                        <span class="dislike" >0</span>
                        <span class="like"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></i></span>
                    </a>
                    </button>
                    <h3>08-Nov-18</h3>
                    <p>Third one</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Page seems to load fine and button also works fine until the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in your Javascript code where you tell the server to update the count. So you're only updating the variables in the browser. That's why the counts are forgotten when you refresh.

You'll either need a form to post to your view to increase the count (thix will refresh the page on each click) or you'll need to use an AJAX call to the server to update the code (this will not refresh the entire page on each click).

Comment: Can't we do it on the given framework? I think PythonAnywhere uses Bootstrap environment. I'll try putting the code in a form and run again.

Comment: It looks like you're using Flask, so you'll need to add new views (functions with `app.route` decorators) to handle upvotes and downvotes, and then you'll need to change your JavaScript to hit those views.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Flask. What change do I need to do in my JavaScript code?